# How to change labels color in valueaxis in chartview in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to change label color of ValueAxis used for  x axis in chartview.

In the above image i have highlighted ScaleAxisXTop in that labels color i used is red ,So it displays number in scale from 1 to 10 in red color but i want even numbers to be in red color and odd numbers to be in green color. Please suggest is there any other ways to get it.

My Sample code as text is here:

```
ChartView {

    id:topScaleChart      
   ValueAxis {
        id: scaleAxisXTop
        min:0
        max:xAxisCount
        tickCount: xAxisCount+1                
        labelsColor:"red"}
    ValueAxis {
        id: scaleAxisYTop
        min:0
        max: 1
        tickCount: 1
       }

    ScatterSeries {
        id: scatterSeriesTop
        axisXTop: scaleAxisXTop
        axisY: scaleAxisYTop
        }
}
```

In this above code i want change scaleAxisXTop label color as red and green based on even and odd.

Comment: Show your code as text

Comment: ChartView {
                    id:topScaleChart      
                   ValueAxis {
                        id: scaleAxisXTop
                        min:0
                        max:xAxisCount
                        tickCount: xAxisCount+1                
                        labelsColor:"red"}
                    ValueAxis {
                        id: scaleAxisYTop
                        min:0
                        max: 1
                        tickCount: 1}                  
}  In this scaleAxisXTop labels color i want to give red and green based on even and odd

Comment: The worst thing you can do is put code in the comments, nobody will understand and not give importance, what I have said is that you edit your question and add the code all, read [ask]

Comment: sorry i have edited my question.plz check